# Overloaded operator with empty body magically works

Tags: c++

I've come across the following strange behaviour and I can't figure out what is happening.

I have a vector class called `mvec` that stores actual values in an array, and a class `mvec_transf` that is a transformation of another vector. It stores a reference to the other vector, and a unary function that defines the transformation. This is how it can be used:

```
mvec<int, 3>                                vec1 {1, 2, 3};
mvec_transf<mvec<int, 3>, std::negate<int>> vec2 {vec1, std::negate<int>()};
// `vec2` contains [-1 -2 -3]
```

I overloaded `operator-` such that I could write `auto vec2 = -vec1;`, and this is my current implementation:

```
template <class Vec_t>
mvec_transf<Vec_t, std::negate<typename Vec_t::elem_t>>
operator- (Vec_t& v)
{  /*std::out << "Hello from operator- " << std::endl;*/ }
```

Mysteriously, this implementation (without a body) works. If I comment out the definition, I get a *no match for operator-* error from the compiler. If I don't, the code compiles with warnings *missing return type* and *unused variable 'v'*. When I run `auto vec2 = -vec1`, `vec2` actually contains a working `mvec_transf<..>` object, which has a correct reference to `vec1`.

By adding a print statement, I can confirm that the overloaded operator actually gets called. With the print statement, however, `vec2` contains a reference to garbage instead of a reference to `vec1`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is just undefined behavior. From [stmt.return]:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

One type of undefined behavior is magically working code. Another type is magically destroying-your-harddrive code. I wouldn't rely on it magically working for very long. Fix it!

Comment: don't forget the [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)